# Powershell: use Select-String to get the first match out of each file in a directory

Tags: powershell, text-files, select-string

Using PowerShell, I need to get the first instance of a match from each (text) file in the directory.

The relevant section of the file looks like this:

TANK PRODUCT               VOLUME TC-VOLUME   ULLAGE   HEIGHT    WATER    TEMP

1  Unleaded                2275         0     7606    34.83     0.00   70.12

Further down in the file, there are more instances of the word "Unleaded", but I need to get the Volume (2275 in this case) from this line.

This script:
$u_line = (Select-String -Path ".\TMUSite_*.sav" -Pattern "Unleaded" | Select-Object * -First 1).Line
Gets me:
1  Unleaded                2275         0     7606    34.83     0.00   70.12

... and that's fine because I can pull the number out of there with a [regex]::matches, or something. The problem is that there are about 10 files in the directory and I need to get this value out of all of them. Right now I only get the match from the first file.

I was expecting to get an array of lines similar to above. I thought the "-First 1" was getting me the first match and that this would happen for each file. The benefit of using Select-String is the object that it returns, in that it includes the file name which has an ID in it that I have to tie the extracted values to, probably in a PSCustomObject. But for now I can only get that first line.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought the "-First 1" was getting me the first match and that this would happen for each file.

- No, it gets only the first output object *overall*, across all files.
- Also note that you don't need `Select-Object *` (short for: `Select-Object -Property *` with `-First`; in fact, if you do so, you unnecessarily create *copies* of `Select-String`'s output objects.

Instead, use [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string)'s `-List` switch to limit output to one match *per file*.

```bash
Select-String -List -Path ".\TMUSite_*.sav" -Pattern "Unleaded"
```

Answer (score 0):

To select the first one for each file (though `-List` is better!):

```bash
$Unleaded = (Get-Item -Path ".\TMUSite_*.sav" | foreach { 
  Select-String -path $_ -Pattern "Unleaded" | Select-Object -First 1 
})
```

From there, you can access both `$unleaded.Line` for the text, and `$Unleaded.Filename` or `.Path` for those. Your original example used `$u_line = (...).Line`, so it was discarding the other properties